# How do I delete a list within a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

My program involves drawing a card from a deck, adding the value of it to my hand and then deleting the card from the deck (since I don't want to draw the same card twice).

Example of a card:

```
card = ["4 of clubs", 4]
```

The code that doesn't work:

```
card_number = random.randrange(len(deck_cards))
card = deck_cards[card_number][0]
print(card)
hand_value += deck_cards[card_number][1]
deck_cards.remove(card_number)
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, and if I change the code to

```
card_number = random.chioce(deck_cards)
```

it won't accept the `card = deck_cards[card_number][0]` part.

What to do?

Comment: `deck_cards.remove(card_number)` should be `deck_cards.remove(deck_cards[card_number])`  The parameter is the element to remove, not its index.  Try typing `help(list.remove)` in the REPL.  It will tell you, `L.remove(value) -> None -- remove first occurrence of value.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`list.remove`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) takes an object, not an index, as parameter.

So you should modify your code to retrieve a card and use it directly:

```py
>>> card = random.choice(deck_cards) # Retrieve an object, not an index
>>> print (card) # card is you card list, i.e.:
["4 of clubs", 4]
>>> print (card[0])
4 of clubs
>>> hand_value += card[1]
>>> deck_cards.remove (card)
```

Note that you can also delete an object at a specified index using the `del` built-in:

```py
>>> card_number = random.randrange(len(deck_cards))
>>> card = deck_cards[card_number][0]
>>> print(card)
"4 of clubs"
>>> hand_value += deck_cards[card_number][1]
>>> del deck_cards[card_number]
```

Comment: Thank you! That works, but is there any way I can have the code disply only the first part?

Comment: @JesperVines Simply `print(card[0])` instead of `print(card)`.

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice(list)` returns a random element of the list, but the list `deck_cards[card_number]` expects the position of the item to retrieve from the list (hence an integer). So just stating `card = random.choice(deck_cards)[0]` is sufficient.

Also, using a list as reprensentation of a card is a poor choice, because it does not represent the object characteristic of a card. If you wrote you own class for cards, your code would become much more readable. If the class would look like this:

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
```

and you instantiated a card like `card = Card('4 of clubs', 4)`, you could write code like `hand_value = deck_cards[index].value` and get rid of those ugly indices. Of curse you would have to write you own string presenter for this class for easy fancy output of a card, but that's not to hard either.

So (without that string representational code) you problem would be solved like this:

```
card = random.choice(deck_cards)
print('{},{}'.format(card.name, card.value))
hand_value += card.value
deck_cards.remove(card)
```